# how can I find the PTR file for the revers DNS record

Tags: linux, centos, dns

where can I find the file that include the PTR result?

this file ( smtp-relay.mycar.com.)
or this (41.32.28.172.in-addr.arpa.)

#dig +noall +answer -x 172.28.32.41

41.32.28.172.in-addr.arpa. 1200 IN     PTR     smtp-relay.mycar.com.

@@@@@@@@@@@@

another method

## host 172.28.32.41

41.32.28.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer smtp-relay.mycar.com.

Comment: `whois 172.125.32.41` says it is owned by AT&T, so ask them. It also resolves to `172-125-32-41.lightspeed.cicril.sbcglobal.net.`, so no idea where you get your result. `smtp-relay.mycar.com` does not resolve.

Comment: sorry, replace the IP to 172.28.32.41, i will edit the question, thanks